# How to send dynamic button url to Iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I've generated a button dynamically and I need to use click event to target those links to the iframe, here is the generation code for button,

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbl; i++)
    {
        LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
        lnkBtn.CssClass = "btn";
        lnkBtn.Text = textList[i];
        lnkBtn.PostBackUrl = linkList[i];
        LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
        table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(lnkBtn);
        table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(linebreak);
    }
```

PostBackUrl and Button Text comes from the Database and for loop turns to the number of rows of the database table. I need to show each button's link into Iframe. Iframe has id like "myFrame".

Comment: What do you mean by "show each button link into iFrame?"

Comment: I'm sorry about my english, I want to click to the button and display them into iframe at the same page.

Comment: You don't need to apologise, your English is great! Just trying to figure out what you want to do... So you have a button outside an iFrame, then when you click the button you want the iFrame to change to a different URL?

Comment: Yes exactly. I used linkbutton and url 's are coming from database. I also found code like  

HtmlControl myFrame = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("myFrame");
myFrame.Attributes["src"] ="URL";

but This code is inside button_click event cause buttons are static.

Comment: Did you see the updated answer @OykunYenal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give your iFrame a `name` attribute, this can be the same as the ID if you like. Then your link will use this as its `target`, so in turn, any clicks will trigger a change on the iFrame.

```
<a href="your-url-here.html" target="myFrame">Foo</a>
<iframe id="myframe" name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

To achieve this, you'll need to add the target to your LinkButton:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbl; i++)
{
    HyperLink lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
    lnkBtn.CssClass = "btn";
    lnkBtn.Text = textList[i];
    lnkBtn.NavigateUrl = linkList[i];
    lnkBtn.Target = "myFrame";
    LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
    table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(lnkBtn);
    table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(linebreak);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I gave the link to the button with PostBackUrl property. I guess something wrong with that it's not working.

Comment: Sorry! I don't think you want to use a LinkButton as this will cause a postback, a HyperLink is better. I've updated my example.